# Reading unknown symbols as strings in at-exp languages

Tags: racket, scribble

I have created a module which provides various functions, including #%module-begin. I want to use it with at-exp syntax, which I can do using the following #lang line:

```
#lang at-exp s-exp "my-library.rkt"
```

However, this does not read unknown symbols as strings, as would happen for example when using the scribble/text language. How can I provide this functionality from my library, to save me writing quote marks around all my strings?

I think it may have something to do with the #%top function. Perhaps I can require it somehow from scribble/text and then provide it from my library?

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous: as asked, it would imply that you want unbound identifiers to be replaced with strings, but given you’ve mentioned `scribble/text`, it sounds like what you *actually* want is to start the at-reader in text mode, using the behavior of [`read-inside` and `read-syntax-inside`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/reader-internals.html#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Freader..rkt%29._read-syntax-inside%29%29). Is that accurate?

Comment: I'm ignorant as to what the difference is. My goal is to turn unquoted symbols into strings so that I don't have to quote them when writing. Does starting the at-reader in text mode do more than that? For example, I don't want it to display the rendered text when run, which is something that I see that scribble/text does. Edit: When I say quoted, I mean "like this", not 'like 'this.

Comment: The `scribble/text` language does print it out, but only in the same way that `#lang racket/base "hello"` prints out `"hello"`. But that's `#%module-begin`'s job to handle that. If you don't want that to happen, you should provide a `#%module-begin` to make sure that `(#%module-begin "hello")` doesn't print out `"hello"`.

Comment: Thanks Alex - it's so obvious now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `scribble/text` does, is it starts reading the file in "text" mode, whereas `at-exp` starts reading the file in "racket" mode. Messing with `#%top` is not what you want here. To do the same thing as `scribble/text`, you would need a version of `at-exp` that starts in text mode. That doesn't exist (yet) though.

The function [`read-syntax-inside`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/reader-internals.html#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Freader..rkt%29._read-syntax-inside%29%29) from `scribble/reader` does this. However, you will have to define your own `#lang` language that uses it. For that, you might find [this documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-languages.html) helpful, but there's no quick answer.

#### Update:

I looked at the [implementation of `scribble/text`](https://github.com/racket/scribble/blob/master/scribble-text-lib/scribble/text/lang/reader.rkt), and the answer seems a lot quicker than I thought it would be. Something like this should work:

`my-library/lang/reader.rkt`:

```
#lang s-exp syntax/module-reader

my-library/main

#:read        scribble:read-inside
#:read-syntax scribble:read-syntax-inside
#:whole-body-readers? #t
#:info        (scribble-base-reader-info)

(require (prefix-in scribble: scribble/reader)
         (only-in scribble/base/reader scribble-base-reader-info))
```

Testing it:

```
#lang my-library
This is text
@(list 'but 'this 'is 'not)
```

I tested this with `my-library/main.rkt` re-providing everything from `racket/base`.